# Is there a go-to/search planet?

Tags: stellaris

A good event happened in one of the planets, we know the name of that planet and now need to find its location.

Is there another way beside eyeballing each planet?

Comment: Related to your answer: in the corner of most windows, including events, is a picture of a camera and crosshairs. Clicking this will zoom to the appropriate location

Comment: @Landric I was going to put that down as an answer. Would upvote it if you did.

Comment: It is important to note that **the search field is case sensitive**. For example, entering "earth" into the search field will not return any results (unless a planet or system has been manually renamed "earth" in lower case). Searching for "**E**arth" however should return the Sol system wherein Earth is located.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Look in the lower right corner of the screen. There is a small bar with several icons, one of them, I think the magnifying glass, may also be the question mark is search planet. Just enter the name of the planet in the window popping up.

Alternatively, use the tried and true paradox hotkey: F to find.

Comment: You can also search on systems and empires.

Comment: The really confusing thing is that the search results only show you the star system name, and not the name of the planet you were searching for.

Comment: @tgharold What is confusing about that? It should be easy enough to find the planet, when the search tells you the system the planet is in.

Comment: When someone starts playing Stellaris, they'll find it confusing that the search results do not contain the text that they were searching for and will consider the search tool to be broken / unsuitable for finding planets.  It does technically work, but is not ideal from a UI transparency standpoint.

Answer (score 4):

Pressing F will bring up the search window. The results however only show the name of the **System** that contains the planet that you searched for.

Answer (score -1):

Just search the name of the planet using the methods above, and the search results will return the systems hosting planets with the same name.

Comment: Hi bcyy, 10x for your good will and comment. This is indeed not an answer, it adds little and even almost nothing to the marked answer. Again, 10x for the effort.